# Почему String неизменяемый? и как это помогает программисту?

Tags: java, строки

Что помимо того что нельзя наследоваться от `final` класса, а именно `String.class`, и того что при использовании метода `concat()` и операции `+` будет создан новый объект типа `String` а не изменен существующий, используется при определении неизменяемости класса `String`?

Как неизменяемость (**immutable**) класса **`String`** помогает в реальных ситуациях программисту. Были бы интересны примеры связанные с **HashMap** и многопоточностью.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://tlazarenko.blogspot.ru/2013/10/string-java.html) человек уже ответил на ваш вопрос:

> Безопасность и String pool основные причины неизменяемости String в Java.
>
> Безопасность объекта неизменяемого класса String обусловлена такими фактами:
>
> - вы можете передавать строку между потоками и не беспокоиться что она будет изменена
> - нет проблем с синхронизацией (не нужно синхронизировать операции со String)
> - отсутствие утечек памяти
> - в Java строки используются для передачи параметров для авторизации, открытия файлов и т.д. - неизменяемость позволяет избежать проблем с доступом
> - возможность кэшировать hash code
>
> String pool позволяет экономить память и не создавать новые объекты
>   для каждой повторяющийся строки. В случае с изменяемыми строками -
>   изменение одной приводило бы к изменению всех строк одинакового
>   содержания.

А если нужно изменять, есть StringBuffer.

Comment: на сколько я помню похожее объяснение, только для всех подобных классов, можно встретить в Эффективной Java Блоха