# Интересный случай с конкатенацией

Tags: java, строки, concat

Почему "s.concat(s)" в отдельности не работает а вот при присваивании к новой String или сразу в sout - работает?  Я знаю что String это Immutable класс, и по идее изменять s не получится, и где то я прочел и понял, что во время конкатенации через знак + создается новая строка в памяти, но вроде же в обеих случаев и в случае "s.concat(s);" и в случае "s = s.concat(s);" написан один и тот же код, я про "s.concat(s);"

---

Возможно я не вижу что-то очень элементарное, но все же решил не постесняться немного выглядеть дурачком, но зато получить ответ на важный вопрос, чтобы потом не опозорится во время будущей работы.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "a".concat("b"); //работает
    s.concat(s); //не работает
    s = s.concat(s);//работает
    s.concat("."); //не работает
    //String b = s.concat(s); //работает
    System.out.println(s); //работает
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `String` - неизменяемый (immutable) согласно спецификации класс. В случаях подобных `s.concat(s)` результат операции помещается в кучу (heap), но это уже **новый** объект типа `String`, а объект в памяти, на который указывает ссылка `s` остаётся прежним.

[Почему String неизменяемый? и как это помогает программисту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544413/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-string-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83)

Также искал хорошую картинку, которая демонстрирует именно этот случай, но всё время попадаются объяснения про пул строк, что интересно, но к делу не относится, и вот нашёл http://keysandstrokes.info/java-immutable-strings/

И вот про пул строк на всякий случай https://www.codenuclear.com/string-facts/

Comment: Только уточню, чтобы уже на все 100% убедится что правильно понял вас.  Значит весь смысл  в том, что на самом деле конкатенация происходит, просто нет ссылка указывающего на эту конкатенацию и нет sout или просто присваивания, чтобы они уже включились в дело, так? Если да, тогда у меня все.

Comment: Да. В случае s = s.concat(s) ссылка есть.

Comment: Благодарочка за качественную подачу инфо.

Answer (score 1):

Не работает по-вашему это значит что не выводится результат конкатенации в консоль?

Метод `concat` не модифицирует строку на которой он вызван, он возвращает результат своей работы в виде новой строки (так же как Вы и писали про конкатенацию через оператор `+`).

Во всех случаях, когда Вы написали "работает", Вы используете оператор присваивания, в результате чего значение переменной `s` и меняется.