# Объект типа String все таки изменяемый?

Tags: java

В учебнике Герберта Шилдта "Java Полное руководство", написано, что созданный объект типа String неизменяем, а именно "после того, как объект типа String будет создан, изменить символы, составляющие новую строку, уже нельзя".

Вот этот код добавит символ в конец строки:

```
String str = "world wide";
str += 'x';
```

Как я понимаю, выходит, что объект типа String **изменяемый, но с определенными ограничениями**, такими как, например: нельзя заменить символ в середине, нельзя добавить символ в середину и т.п. Правильно имеются какие либо ещё неточности в формулировках в учебниках?

Comment: так вы получили новую строку, а ссылку на старую - потеряли, но старая -не поменялась

Comment: String не изменяемый. Вот тут `str += 'x';` вы создаете новую строку и пишете её в переменную `str`.

Comment: Думаю, что это будет хорошей подсказкой [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544413/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-string-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83)

Comment: то есть изменять значение переменной `str` != изменить строку. `str` - это всего лишь ссылка на строку, а не сама строка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В примере, который вы показали - это не изменение объекта.
В этот момент `str += 'x';` вы создаёте новую строку и пишете её в переменную str, но на изначальный str со значением `"world wide"` ссылка была утеряна.

```
Безопасность и String pool основные причины неизменяемости String в Java.

Безопасность объекта неизменяемого класса String обусловлена такими фактами:

    1) Вы можете передавать строку между потоками и не беспокоиться что она будет изменена
    2) Нет проблем с синхронизацией (не нужно синхронизировать операции со String)
    3) Отсутствие утечек памяти
    4) В Java строки используются для передачи параметров для авторизации, открытия файлов и т.д. - неизменяемость позволяет избежать проблем с доступом
    5) Возможность кэшировать hash code

String pool позволяет экономить память и не создавать новые объекты для каждой повторяющийся строки. В случае с изменяемыми строками - изменение одной приводило бы к изменению всех строк одинакового содержания.
```

Если нужно изменять, есть StringBuffer.