# Почему String объявлен как final?

Tags: java, строки

Я не понимаю с какой целью String, как и многие другие классы, объявляют с ключевым словом final. Только ради того, чтобы показать другим разработчикам, что семантика final класса не предполагает наследников? Если так, то и в чем, собственно, проблема? Например, даже если бы я смог снять final у String, то унаследовав его, я все равно никак не смогу изменить какой либо экземпляр String. А значит и менее иммутабельным он не стал...

P.S. Да, я знаю, что подобные вопросы найти уже можно, но ответа я не нашел.

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068804/why-is-the-string-class-declared-final-in-java)

Comment: Мне кажется, тут дело в полиморфизме. Если бы класс строки не был финальным, мы могли бы создать разные классы-наследники (зачем-то), а использовать их, как подобает, через родительские классы, в данном случае - через `String`. И тогда получалось бы, что мы вроде как видим `String` (например, ожидаем на вход в метод, объявляем как тип переменной и так далее), а фактически с ним происходят странные вещи: например, он изменяется и прочее. Ну, это моё видение ситуации.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему String неизменяемый? и как это помогает программисту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544413/)

Comment: Если у `String`снять `final`, то гипотетически любой из его методов можно будет переопределить так, что этот класс станет изменяемым.

Answer (score 2):

1. На сколько я понял, конкретно String - это весьма подкопный класс и присвоение ему final может как-то оптимизировать компиляцию и обеспечить безопасность. Какие-либо первоисточники на эту тему не находил, в основном ответы пользователей.
2. Также, как ответил Byb, когда мы предоставляем возможность реализовывать наследников, то за счет полиморфизма сможем по общему интерфейсу/классу посылать в метод как String, так и его наследников. Однако поведение такого метода может сработать некорректно, особенно, когда семантика String вообще не предполагает вмешательств, а наследники могут что-то изменить (нарушение L-SOLID).

Изучая тему обнаружил, что слепо ставить final у классов, которые попросили сделать иммутабельными, необязательно. Если для всех полей/методов поставить модификаторы final private, то изменить объект родительского класса (даже без final в заголовке класса) все равно не получится, а вот просто так брать и ограничивать класс от расширения - это должно быть взвешенным и ответственным решением, показывающим завершение ветви иерархии наследования.

Вот часть ответа, пусть и не самого авторитетного, chatGPT на вопрос "какой класс называют иммутабельным":

> "Класс должен быть Финализированным (Final): Хотя это не обязательное
> условие, но делает класс более безопасным в плане наследования. Если
> класс объявлен как final, то его нельзя подклассировать, и это
> устраняет потенциальные проблемы, связанные с изменением поведения или
> состояния объекта при наследовании."

Comment: _Если для всех полей/методов поставить модификаторы final private, то изменить объект родительского класса (даже без final в заголовке класса) все равно не получится_ -- вот чтобы не ставить кучу `final` для всех полей и методов и решили применять `final` к классу целиком.